# Setting response header for Content-Type as "application/json; charset=utf-16" converts json to chinese character

Tags: node.js, express, utf-16

When I try to set response headers in my service, it converts the json to chinese characters and some other garbage character. I have been trying to debug this issue since 2 days. I am using express server.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple test server that sends a basic json response to the client, I don't see the issue with chinese characters appearing. I've also tested with larger json responses.

You might give this a go and see if you're getting the same result.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/json', (req, res) => {
    res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-16' });
    res.write( JSON.stringify( { foo: 'bar' } ) )
    res.end();
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: still getting the same issue, I tried it on postman, which version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm using Node v10.15.1, Windows 10, Express 4.17.1, hmmm.. I wonder what's causing the difference.. I tested using curl, I'll try postman..

Comment: I think it is an OS related issue, my server is running in ubuntu on aws and i am testing locally on mac

Comment: It could be! I've tested using postman and while I don't see chinese characters, I get an empty response for some reason when using utf-16 character encoding. Curl doesn't seem to care about the encoding.